# How do I troubleshoot devtools

Tags: r, devtools

Out of the blue my devtools package will not work. Here is what I get. I have tried numerous fixes on my Windows 8 machine. I have reinstalled Rtools, I have reinstalled devtools but I keep getting the follwoing

```
require(devtools)


Loading required package: devtools
Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : 
undefined exports: iteratelist, rowSplit, whisker.escape, whisker.render
```

Where do I begin?

Winston Chang over on the devtools github said, "Strange, those errors involve the whisker package." So at his behest I am providing some additional information.

```
> packageVersion('whisker')
[1] ‘0.3.2’
> packageVersion('devtools')
[1] ‘1.3’
> sessionInfo() 
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: What versions of everything that might be involved?

Comment: R 3.0.1, latest everything.

Comment: So no IDE? Everything is from command line and you are using a vanilla call to R from the command line?

Comment: I was using Rstudio, as I always do, when I first encountered the problem. Then I closed Rstudio and used the R GUI that comes with R. Same problem.

Comment: I do not think you have described the results of my suggestion to use install.packages from the omegahat repo. It proceeded without difficulty on a Mac, so I wonder if you have RTools installed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I deleted the whisker folder in ~My Documents\R\win-library\3.0\ and reinstalled the package. Everything worked.

Thanks to Winston Chang who made me realize that my devtools problems were coming from the whisker package which I believe devtools relies on. Thank you to @DWin who gave me the idea of chucking out a malfunctioning library and reinstalling the library.

It was when I issued `library(whisker)` that I realized the problem may not be with devtools at all but rather with whisker

```
> library(whisker)
Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : 
  undefined exports: iteratelist, rowSplit, whisker.escape, whisker.render
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘whisker’
```

I can now load devtools and whisker.

It is odd. I would have thought that my packages would have been reinstalled when I uninstalled R and reinstalled it (one of the desperate steps I took when I was trying to troubleshoot). Evidently ~My Documents\R\win-library\3.0\whisker survived the uninstallation. Clearly I need to learn more about R installation and the ways in which the libraries can be setup.

Answer (score 0):

My guess, in the absence of complete information and a  log file for a command line installation, is that you have a corrupt .RData file. The .Rhistory file might alos be a source of corrupted data that results in incomprehensible error messages. (They are invisible to the average R user on both Windows and Mac file browsers.) Windows Explorer let's you choose to show hidden files. In WinXP  one of the choices off the "Folder Options" dialog is the "View" panel. Delete first the `.Rdata` file and if that doesn't work then also delete the `.Rhistory` file.

My guess was wrong, so if RTools is available then:

```
install.packages("RGoogleDocs", 
                 repos="http://www.omegahat.org/R", type="source")
```

Comment: Thanks. I will use voidtools search everything to find all .RData and all .Rhistory and will delete them. Then lets see what happens....5 minutes later...alas the same problem.

Comment: I only deleted the .rdata and .rhistory that had no filename before the extension. Surely R is not automatically loading anything such as "myimporantproject.RData"?

Comment: Correct. There is not automatic loading of *.Rdata or *.Rda files where * is some string.

Comment: How can I give you more information. Without devtools I cannot install RGoogleDocs from GitHub. There are no windows binaries as far as I know otherwise I could download a zip file containing it.

Comment: I would first try deleting any `devtools` folders in all the directories pointed to by `.libPaths()` and making one last effort at reinstalling that package. Failing that, you should be able to find a source version of the file at: http://www.omegahat.org/RGoogleDocs/RGoogleDocs_0.7-0.tar.gz  That should compile if you have a proper version of RTools for your OS.

Comment: there is also some conversation going on on the [devtools GitHub](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/345)  repository with Winston Chang that you may or may not find illuminating.

Comment: So far it's not very interesting. Although I do agree that you may have gotten to the point where contacting the package authors is the right next step.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, "deleting any devtools folders in all the directories pointed to by .libPaths()." Unfortunately, it did not work. I had the same problem when I reinstalled. I did indeed have RTools installed and so thank you for reminding me how to install RGoogleDocs from omegahat. So now that I have RGoogleDocs installed I am not in the same pickle. Nevertheless, my original question still stands. There is a problem and I do not know what is causing it or how to resolve it.